# Disable "followFinger" option on specific slides in idangero Swiper

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am using idangero [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WLCucW8rKUk) and one of the config options that can be passed in is followFinger.  Does anyone know if we can selectively disable that option on an individual slide, opposed to applying it to the entire Swiper context?

```
var swiper_instance = new Swiper('#main-slider', {followFinger:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually came up with a solution that roughly looks like this:

```
var swiper_instance = new Swiper('#main-slider', {}); 
swiper_instance.on("SlideChangeEnd", function(){
    var _slide = $(_swiper_wrapper).children().eq(swiper_instance.activeIndex);
    var stopSwipe = _slide.hasClass("stop-easy-swipe");
    swiper_instance.params.followFinger = !stopSwipe;
    swiper_instance.update(true);
});
```

Now in my html I set the class 'stop-easy-swipe' to any slide that I don't want the sensitive finger follow set.